# How to drag a 64 stack in a chest into 1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How to drag a 64 stack in a chest into 1? I'm a little tired of doing it 1 by 1.

I have 1.8.7, I don't know if it's a bug but I've tried doing shift click and watching YouTube but I can find anything on how to do this.

Comment: well here more deatail, u have a stack of 64 and u want to get it into a chest by 1 idk how to do it.

Comment: Drag 64 stack(***s***?) in a chest into 1 what?

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to put 1 cobblestone from a stack in the chest? Or that you want to split it into multiple stacks of 1?

Comment: Are you pressing shift, letting go then clicking? It needs to be held down. If you're holding it down, are you pressing left click or right click? Last time I used it, it was Shift + RMB. (Thanks for letting me know, Nick.)

Comment: Could you edit your question and be more clear about what you're asking? Proper grammar/spelling is also appreciated. It's hard to read a question with "plz" and "idk" all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

Not too sure what you're asking here, but here's what you can do stacks of items in the inventory:

###Picking up a stack

- **Left-Click** will pick up the whole stack
- **Right-Click** will pick up half the stack
- **Left Double-Click** will grab up to the maximum stackable amount from stacks of the same item.
- So for example, in the chest below, double clicking on any of the bread or plank piles will collect **all** bread or planks into a single stack:
  [image: Loot chest with various stacks of items]

###Placing stacked items

- **Single Left-Click** will place the whole stack
- **Single Right-Click** will place **one** out of the whole stack
- **Left-Click and Drag** will split the stack evenly between slots you drag over
- This will only occur if the slots you are dragging over are empty or the same stackable item
- **Right-Click and Drag** will place **one** item in each slot you drag over.
- This will only occur if the slots you are dragging over are empty or the same stackable item

###Miscellaneous

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + **Left-Click** Will auto-move an item/stack to the hotbar or into a chest (or vice versa)
- Hovering over an item and pressing <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd> will swap that item into the hotbar at the specified slot number.

You can read more on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Inventory).